# MERN Stack on Heroku Build Failing at heroku-postbuild

Tags: javascript, node.js, git, heroku, mern

Here is the error message I am receiving:

```
-----> Build
       Running heroku-postbuild
       
       > syllame@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild /tmp/build_ded3c540_
       > npm install --prefix client && npm run build && --prefix client
       
       
       > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /tmp/build_ded3c540_/client/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > core-js@3.8.2 postinstall /tmp/build_ded3c540_/client/node_modules/core-js
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > core-js-pure@3.8.1 postinstall /tmp/build_ded3c540_/client/node_modules/core-js-pure
       > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
       
       
       > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /tmp/build_ded3c540_/client/node_modules/ejs
       > node ./postinstall.js
       
       added 1949 packages from 765 contributors and audited 1953 packages in 46.583s
       
       125 packages are looking for funding
         run `npm fund` for details
       
       found 0 vulnerabilities
       
sh: 1: --prefix: not found

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! syscall spawn

npm ERR! file sh

npm ERR! errno ENOENT

npm ERR! syllame@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm install --prefix client && npm run build && --prefix client`

npm ERR! spawn ENOENT

npm ERR! 

npm ERR! Failed at the syllame@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script.

npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.JbA0H/_logs/2021-01-03T20_51_10_460Z-debug.log

-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       Some possible problems:
       
       - node_modules checked into source control
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/node-best-practices#only-git-the-important-bits
       
       - Node version not specified in package.json
         https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#specifying-a-node-js-version
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

Above is the Heroku log after npm successfully installs. I tried removing the hidden .git folder in client, but there is none (yes, i checked the "show hidden files: option in windows explorer as well). I also tried multiple committing and recommitting to no avail via other stackflow tutorials. I have been stuck for a week and finally "gave up", which is why I am asking the question here.
I also tried using the following :  "heroku-postbuild" : "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build && --prefix client

That still does not work. The application is fully functional in localhost/ local environment.
I even tried completely deleting client folder. Still same error.
Defining node and npm in "engines" in package.json also did not change anything.
There is nothing else I can think of.
I tried using Heroku CLI, same issue.
I am using visual studio code.

My project structure:

```
app/
 client/

 config/
 models/
 node_modules
 routes/
 validation
 LICENSE
 package-lock.json
 package.json
 README.md
 server.js
```

Here is my server.js code:

```
const express = require ('express'); //node.js flexible web application framework that provides features for web applications
const mongoose = require ("mongoose"); // Mongoose is a MongoDB object modeling toold designed to work in an asynchronous environment, supporting both promises and callbacks
const bodyParser = require ("body-parser"); //node.js body parsing middleware
const passport = require("passport"); //used to authenticate requests, via plugins known as  ~strategies~.
const path = require("path");

const users = require("./routes/api/users");

const app = express();
//body parser middleware

app.use(
    bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
    })
);
app.use(bodyParser.json());

//configure our database connection
const db = require("./config/keys").mongoURI;

//actually connecting to our database
mongoose
    .connect(
        db, 
        { useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true}
    )
    .then( () => console.log("Mongo DB connected successfully!"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

//middleware for passport
app.use(passport.initialize());

//configure the passport
require("./config/passport")(passport);

//our routes
app.use("/api/users", users);

//serve our static assets (build folder if we are in production)

if(process.env.NODE_ENV=== 'production') {
    //set static folder
    app.use(express.static('client/build'))


    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'client', 'build' , 'index.html'));

    })
}


    const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; //process.env.PORT is heroku's port if you choose to deploy the app

    app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server up and running on port ${port} !`));
```

and my package.json on the server side

```
{
  "name": "syllame",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild" : "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build && --prefix client"
  },

  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/bbobbylon/syllame.git"
  },
  "author": "Robert C. Oliver, Jr. and Colin J. McClintic",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/bbobbylon/syllame/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/bbobbylon/syllame#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "concurrently": "^5.3.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "is-empty": "^1.2.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^8.5.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.11.9",
    "passport": "^0.4.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.5.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: your postbuild script is `npm install --prefix client && npm run build && --prefix client` should it not be `npm install --prefix client && npm run build  --prefix client` (without the seccond `&&` ?) I think the install and run build commands are working but with the extra `&&` it is interpreting `--prefix client` as another command to run after instead of being part of `npm run build` and thus it fails here because `--prefix` is not a command. I think this is why the first error line is `sh: 1: --prefix: not found` because it isn't an sh command!

Comment: This error would not have come up on your local machine because I doubt you would have run the heroku-postbuild script locally